# I have installed progress database in vm ware virtual machine but I can not connect from my host

Tags: database, vmware, openedge, database-connectivity, progress-db

I have installed progress openedge database on my vmware linux machine but I can not login through host winodws 7. I tried to use datadirect and openedge data admin tools. Can even please guide me how to do it. My connectiong is working from windows to vm ware linux.

Thanks

Comment: When you start up the database which interface does it say it is binding to? `0.0.0.0` or `127.0.0.1`?

Answer (score 0):

Can you connect from within your Linux environment?  IOW -- does this work:

```
proenv> sqlexp -db DBNAME -S PORT# -user USERNAME -password PASSWORD
```

If that doesn't work then it doesn't much matter if you are trying to connect from Windows7 or not.